# Issue understanding dirname file location | PHP

Tags: php

I am practicing writing in php and learning about the php syntax. I'm a bit confused about the following function:

```
function __construct()
{
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/constants.php';
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
    // opening db connection
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();

}
```

When stating `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/constants.php';` where is constants.php located?

Comment: The manul states: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php also read some of the comments.

Comment: The inbuilt PHP constant `__FILE__` refers to the actual PHP file your `__construct()` function resides in.  The `dirname()` inbuilt PHP function trims the filename part off, just leaving the directory e.g. if your current file was /var/www/index.php you would end up with /var/www when you call `dirname(__FILE__)`. It's an accepted way of including a file 'relative' to your current file.

Comment: An alternative method would be `require_once __DIR__ . '/constants.php';`  ~ again, `__DIR__` is another pre-defined magic constant.

Answer (score 0):

here both files are stored in same location. suppose you are having a file inside c:\xampp\htdocs\test\ called index.php. and the content in the file is **require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/constants.php';**. then the file constants.php also located in c:\xampp\htdocs\test\

eg: in your root folder ie. c:\xampp\htdocs\test\
contain two files
1. index.php
2. constants.php